# Java this and super keywords

Tags: java, this, super

I've got a question about Java this and super keywords,  let's take some examples

Firts example

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends Frame {
        //constructor of the class 
        public Main () {
                super ("My frame");
                setSize (200,100);
                setVisible (true);
        }

        public static void main (String [] args) {
                 new Main ();
         }
}
```

second example

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends Frame {
        //constructor of the class 
        public Main () {
                //here the difference from example 1    
                super ("My frame");
                super.setSize (200,100);
                super.setVisible (true);
        }

        public static void main (String [] args) {
                 new Main ();
         }
}
```

Which example is better and why?

Now let's take some examples about this keyword

```
public class Main {
        public void print () {
                System.out.println ("Hi");
        }

        public static void main (String [] args) {
                 print();
         }
}
```

Second example

```
public class Main {

        public void print () {
                System.out.println ("Hi");
        }

        public static void main (String [] args) {
                 //here the difference
                 this.print();
         }
}
```

Which is better and why? 
Thank you for your answers

Comment: You should use it to remove ambiguity where it is needed, but stay as consistent as possible.

Comment: First set: there is no difference, unless you've overriden `setSize` or `setVisible` in `Main`, because `super.XXX` explicitly will call the method as it is defined in the `Frame` class.  With that said, the convention is to only use `super` when necessary.

Comment: Second set: Your second example won't compile because there's no enclosing object for `this` to refer to, so you'll likely prefer the first example there :)

Comment: So super and this are not so so similar. I can use this only if I have an istance of my class,  but I can use super even though I haven't got an istance, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `super` only when you really need to.  If you override `setSize()` then you would find the second example would not call your overridden methods.  This is not necessarily desired behaviour and therefore you should generally just call methods without the `super` prefixing operator.  It's generally best to write code such that it can be extended or maintained without having to worry about whether or not some overrides will actually override from certain methods or not.  Also see Vulcan's comment rendering the issue null and void.